# Handling runtime changes like orientation in android

Tags: android

Am developing an application for android tablet. Have differnt layouts for portrait and landscape. How to persist the data on orientation change? I read through the document, but would like to see a sample code for onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() ?

In one of the screens, i have a video view and several other views. Video will be streamed from a server. Now on orientation change, how to save the buffered stream? I need the % of streaming to be persisted on orientation change, though its showed in a differnt layout(layout,layout-land)

Should i use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() or onSavedInstance here?

Some sample code/demos will be helpfull..

Regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is deprecated. Use the new approach with fragments:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

On orientation changes the activity is re-created but the fragment stays as is.

Comment: Am not using fragments in my view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some work when the rotation changes, you should overwrite onConfigurationChanged(). You'll find more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Here's an example:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration conf)
{      
    super.onConfigurationChanged(conf);
    //do your stuff
}
```

I am sorry, but I can't provide you an example of saving a Buffered Stream because I haven't worked with it yet.

Comment: I saw that. But haven't got much clarity on how exactly it will be implemented. Can you throw some light here by giving a small example?